# Qual a implementação que eu usaria para inicializar os dados no banco usando relacionamento 1:N?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Minha intenção é inicializar uma `SubCategoria`, mas ela precisa de uma `Categoria` primeiro (1:N). Queria saber qual a implementação que eu usaria para este relacionamento dar certo para inicializar no banco de dados? Estou usando o método `Seed` do EntityFramework.

Método `Seed`

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
        {
            IList<Categoria> CategoriasInicialização = new List<Categoria>();
            IList<UnidadeDeMedida> UndMedidasInicialização = new List<UnidadeDeMedida>();
            IList<SubCategoria> SubCategoriaInicialização = new List<SubCategoria>();

            #region Inicialização das SubCategorias

            SubCategoriaInicialização.Add(new SubCategoria() { SubCategoriaNome = "Controlados" });

            foreach (var subCategorias in SubCategoriaInicialização)
                context.SubCategorias.Add(subCategorias);

            #endregion

            #region Inicialização das Categorias

            CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Medicamentos" });
            CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Generos Alimenticios" });
            CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Materiais de Construção" });
            CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Materiais Hospitalar" });
            CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Materiais Odontologico" });

            foreach (var categorias in CategoriasInicialização)
                context.Categorias.Add(categorias);

            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
}
```

Classe de mapeamento da SubCategoria

```
public SubCategoriaConfig()
        {
            ToTable("SubCategoria");
            HasKey(c => c.SubCategoriaId);

            Property(x => x.SubCategoriaNome)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(60);

            HasRequired(x => x.Categoria)
                .WithMany(x => x.SubCategorias)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("CategoriaId"));
        }
```

Comment: Você acrescentou ao final o  context.SaveChanges(); antes do base.Seed(context);

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio Desde já agradeço sua resposta. Realmente esqueci de copiar e colar o método `context.SaveChanges()`, mas já concertei. Eu estava pensando em fazer isso (sou iniciante, ok?!): 
`CategoriasInicialização.Add(new Categoria() { CategoriaNome = "Medicamentos", SubCategorias = SubCategoriaInicialização });`

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio Existe outro modo elegante de fazer isso?

Comment: Na Model Categoria possui várias SubCategorias é isto ?

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio Correto.

Comment: Fiz de maneira mais simples, dá uma olhada para ver se entendi direito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi direito as suas Models, seria algo assim mais simples:

```
var categorias= new List<Categoria>{
                         new Categoria{ CategoriaNome = "Medicamentos" },
                         new Categoria{ CategoriaNome = "Generos Alimenticios" },
                         new Categoria{ CategoriaNome = "Materiais de Construção" },
                         new Categoria{ CategoriaNome = "Materiais Hospitalar" },
                         new Categoria{ CategoriaNome = "Materiais Odontologico" }
};

    categorias.ForEach(x=> context.Categorias.Add(x));
    context.SaveChanges();


    var subCategorias= new List<SubCategoria>{
            new SubCategoria{ SubCategoriaNome = "Controlados", Categoria= categorias.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CategoriaNome.Equals("Medicamentos") },
            new SubCategoria{ SubCategoriaNome = "Controlados 2", Categoria= categorias.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CategoriaNome.Equals("Medicamentos") }
    };

        subCategorias.ForEach(s => context.SubCategoria.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

      categorias[0].SubCategorias.Add(subcategorias[0]); 
      categorias[0].SubCategorias.Add(subcategorias[1]);

      context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Gostei da sua implementação. Principalmente das expressões lambda. Irei usar algo parecido! Obrigado!